# Python Beautifulsoup decompose removing elemets out of element

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I got a DB of files from `theguardian.com`. I need to reduce these files to only text and remove all Ads and other text. I am able to get the main text but when I try to remove the bottom element `("div", attrs={"class": "submeta"})` it deletes the whole text, but the text is not part of this element.

[Input file](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2018/apr/05/clear-discrimination-south-sudanese-react-to-exclusion-from-migration-program)

```py
# Decomposing
for remove1 in soup.select("figure", attrs={"class": "element-atom"}):
    remove1.decompose()
for remove2 in soup.select("aside", attrs={"data-component": "rich-link"}):
    remove2.decompose()
for remove3 in soup.select("div", attrs={"class": "submeta"}):
    remove3.decompose()

# Extraction of text
textHeadline = soup.find("h1", attrs={"class": "content__headline"})
textUnderline = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "tonal__standfirst"})
textBody = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "content__article-body from-content-api js-article__body"})


# Final text
reductionResult = str(textHeadline) + str(textUnderline) + str(textBody)
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.find_all()` instead of `.select()` to select elements to decompose. `.select()` is used only with CSS selectors:

```
for remove1 in soup.find_all("figure", attrs={"class": "element-atom"}):
    remove1.decompose()
for remove2 in soup.find_all("aside", attrs={"data-component": "rich-link"}):
    remove2.decompose()
for remove3 in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "submeta"}):
    remove3.decompose()

textHeadline = soup.find("h1", attrs={"class": "content__headline"})
textUnderline = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "tonal__standfirst"})
textBody = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "content__article-body from-content-api js-article__body"})

# Final text
reductionResult = str(textHeadline) + str(textUnderline) + str(textBody)
print(reductionResult)
```

Prints:

```
<h1 class="content__headline" itemprop="headline">
'Clear discrimination': South Sudanese react to exclusion from migration program
</h1><div class="tonal__standfirst u-cf">

...and so on.
```